# Truncate text for last elements if needed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code (I'm using bootsrap 4):

```html
<div class="badge-container">
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">One</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Two</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Three</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Four</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Five</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Six</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Seven</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Eight</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Nine</span>
</div>
```

My `badge-container` has a fixed width, 150px for example, and should be on one single line. So all the badge elements are not fitting in (I don't know in advance the number of `badge`).

I'd like the first elements overflowing my div ended with `...` and the next elements should be hidden. Like this for example:

> One Thow Three Fo...

I tried the following CSS:

```css
.badge-container {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
}

// I can use text-truncate class instead
.badge {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But it's not working as all elements are truncated...

How would you achieve this?
Is this possible in pure CSS?

Comment: Well going with flexbox might not be the best idea for that, because that “squishes” elements to try and make them fit into one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove flexbox and keep it simple:

```css
.badge-container {
  background: red;
  width: 170px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.badge-container .badge {
  display:inline; /*Remove this to have a different rendring*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="badge-container">
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">One</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Two</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Three</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Four</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Five</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Six</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Seven</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Eight</span>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Nine</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but there is problems with this solutions. First, the dots are outside the badge, so it is rendering in superposition with the badge. Then we see the next badge element in some case (check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/46b92mqr/1/)

Comment: @youri I added the `display:inline` in the code, remove/add it and you will have a different rendring depending if you want to see a complete badge or not

Answer (score 1):

This should work as expected:

```
.badge-container {
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

// I can use text-truncate class instead
.badge {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Is it possible to put the three dots in a `badge` or to style it?

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the solution, your problem was that you were applying the truncate code to the elements it self, and it has to be to the container to have the desired behaviour. Something like this:

```css
.badge-container {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="badge-container">
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">One</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Two</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Three</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Four </span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Five</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Six</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Seven</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Eight</span>
        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Nine</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but there is problems with this solutions. First, the dots are outside the badge, so it is rendering in superposition with the badge. Then we see the next badge element in some case (check my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/46b92mqr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    HTML
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <div class="badge-container">
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">One</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Two</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Three</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Four</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Five</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Six</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Seven</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Eight</span>
      <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Nine</span>
    </div>

    CSS
   .badge-container {
  background: red;
  width: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.badge-container .badge {
  display:inline; /*Remove this to have a different rendring*/
}

.badge-container:hover {
   overflow:visible;
    width: 400px;
   }
```